# Castle Windsor container.Resolve produces null reference exception

Tags: castle-windsor

In my Visual Studio environment my project that uses Castle Windsor dependency injection runs correctly.

When deployed to a target environment however, it fails to start. Capturing exceptions has show this issue:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
    at My.MyService..ctor()
    at My.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

I checked registrations but everything seems OK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my installer failed to deploy some of the dll's. Once that was fixed, the above exception disappeared.

Takeaway: when a type fails to load dependency resolution, you receive a NullReferenceExecption. It'd be more friendly to get a TypeLoadException as the framework does when a library is not available.